# Ideas for fast-converging basis set of C[0,1] with specific boundary conditions?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I have a rather simple and basic questions but really need some help here - I'm looking for a series of functions ${\{f_n\}}$ that span the space of continuous functions defined on C[0,1], with Dirichlet and Neumann BC at x=1: $f_n(1)=0$ and $f_n'(1)=0$, and ideally Neumann BC at x=0: $f_n(0)=0$

The reason I'm looking for such a series is using it as the set radial probe functions up to a certain cutoff distance (I'd love to clarify if that doesn't make sense), therefore it would be great if the series are orthogonal/converges fast.

So far I've thought about radial basis functions and polynomials (Legendre polynomial, for example ), but they don't satisfy the boundary conditions, unfortunately. Any ideas of an already existing series or ways of modifying the existing series would be greatly appreciated, even if they don't satisfy all of the constraints.

Answer (score 1):

> polynomials (Legendre polynomial, for example ), but they don't satisfy the boundary conditions, unfortunately.

Some ideas to try:

1. Trigonometric polynomials
2. Any polynomial basis times $x(x-1)^2$